# how to read SNMP for bandwidth using php

Tags: php, snmp, flot

I would like to get data using SNMP from a router. The data shall be used for a graph I guess using the jquery flot.

But my issue is I do not know how to get my webpage to read the data using SNMP from the router.

I normally use MRTG but I would like to learn how to handcode it if possible.

BR. Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `phpinfo()` to check if your server's PHP binary was built with SNMP support.  If so, you can do this:

```
<?php

$snmp_values = snmpwalk("10.0.0.1", "public", null);

print_r($snmp_values);
```

Where "10.0.0.1" is your router's IP; this will give you the SNMP values returned by your router (different routers return different data), and you can write a script to process that data.

Comment: Super. Got this from phpinfo(): NET-SNMP Support enabled, NET-SNMP Version 5.4.1. Now I will look into the the snmpwalk function. Thanks a lot.